# POST request empty (body-parser extended: true) - still not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, body-parser

I am stumped. **I am making a simple fetch() to the backend where I log request body i.e.**  `console.log(req.body.form_data)`

**Problem:** returning {} empty json object.

**Attempt:** I have installed body-parser i.e

```
 app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
   // body parser - parse json in body.requests
    app.use(bodyParser.json());   // to support JSON-encoded bodies
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true  }));        // to support URL-encoded bodies
```

What is wrong?

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// body parser - parse json in body.requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());   // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true              // to support URL-encoded bodies
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

let users = [];

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.body.form_data) {
    console.log(req.body.form_data)
    // res.json(users);
  }
  console.log(req.body)

  res.render('index', { title: 'TO DO APP' });
});
module.exports = router;
```

myscript.js

```
document.getElementById("listForm").addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    const list_name = document.getElementById("list-name").value;
    const list_date = document.getElementById("list-date").value;

     var form_data = { 
         fname: fname,
         list_name: list_name,
         list_date: list_date
    };
    console.log(form_data );


    // AJAX fetch()
    fetch('/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers(),
        body: form_data
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log("response..");
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(user_json) {
        console.log(user_json);
    });
});
```

index.pug

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p First, create your list

  form#listForm(method="POST" action="/")
    input(type='text' id="fname" name='fname' autofocus placeholder="your name")
    input(type='text' id="list-name" name='list-name' autofocus placeholder="name your list")
    input(type='date' id="list-date" name='list-date' autofocus placeholder="today's date") 
    button(type='submit') Create List
```

Comment: Try using this: `var router = express();` I don't know if that makes a difference, but try. Strongly feel the problem is in the `index.js`. But check your console to see if you are really making any AJAX calls.

Comment: u mean: var router = express.Router(); to var router = express(); .. didn't change anything

Comment: are you passing headers `content-type: application/json`?? Without it the body parser won't be able to know that you've passed json and it needs to parse it.

Comment: No i am using headers() as written in fetch() body... would do you mean? example

Comment: inside index.js what is result of this line:
  console.log(req.body)
can you add your log results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need to pass the `content-type` header with your request which you're not sending currently. Also you would need to convert it into a JSON string by using `JSON.stringify` like below.

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('content-type','application/json');
fetch('/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(form_data)
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log("response..");
    return response.json();
}).then(function (user_json) {
    console.log(user_json);
});
```

Comment: Okay turns out console.log(req.body) is printing the request BUT NOT console.log(req.body.form_data)... any ideas??

Comment: Because you haven't passed form_data as field, fields are fname, list_name, list_date. It should show `req.body.form_data` as `undefined`

Comment: Oh. In my backend i need to check for different post requests i.e. if(form_data) if(form2_data) etc.. what is the right way of sending my json object to make it work like this?

Comment: How would you do it? send an array with json object as elements is the only method i can think of

Comment: Why do you need to that way? Isn't it the correct way? You should access the keys like `req.body.firstName` and something like that. I don't think what you are trying to do is a good idea.

Comment: Really? I thought instead of having multiple if statements to check if all the input values are sent i..e if(req.body.firstName) nested if(req.body.date) etc. save data to db. it would be better to check if the form was submitted with all the properties

Comment: Its not possible actually to do the way you want to do but to reduce multiple if statement s you can have them in a single if statement with `&&`

Comment: Yeah that works too. But I don't like that way it seems unclean
. I know jquery has a serialize method which could be used to covert form data into json object, however, Im not using jquery... perhaps i'll create my own serialize method to do this